How to make a NAND gate with vaccum tubes?
We all know the NAND gate with mosfets. However, a lot of history of computers is unknown. Can you please let me know a diagram of a NAND gate with mosfets how is it made with vacuum tubes or a Dflipflop? There is a small link for it. The analytical abilities of those in 1900s must have been very high.
https://hackaday.io/project/169147-low-voltage-vacuum-tube-logic-gates/

The design of gates, at the transistor/physics/circuits level, is probably out of scope for our site, but might be on topic for Electrical Engineering SE.  This site's scope is everything relating to bits and higher levels of abstraction.

So... let's try to answer this in a computer sciency way, so we can get across the general idea without knowing too much about electronics.
But first, let's be clear on what we mean by "the NAND gate with MOSFETs".
Historically, there have been essentially two ways to make a NAND gate out of MOSFETs: NMOS and CMOS. NMOS is easier and uses fewer transistors, so that was common in the early days of VLSI. CMOS is faster and lower-power, so is the design of choice today.

The NMOS circuit uses a pull-up resistor (actually a depletion mode MOSFET, but it's best thought of as a resistor) which, if the rest of the circuit were not there, would result in the output being 1. There are, additionally, two N-type MOSFETs in series, which you can think of as gates. If one or both of the MOSFETs are turned, then it's almost like they were open circuits, meaning the output will be 1. But if both of the MOSFETs are turned on, that gives a path to ground which is "stronger" than the resistor, resulting in the output being 0.
The bottom half of the CMOS circuit is identical, but the top half is very different. Instead of the pull-up resistor, it is the complementary circuit. Instead of two series N-type MOSFETs creating a path to zero, it is two parallel P-type MOSFETs creating a path to one.
I bring this up because you might be referring to either one of these. But just as a comment, you could also design this gate using only the top-half of the CMOS design, and instead of the bottom half, have a pull-down resistor to zero. A "PMOS" design, if you will. There are good reasons why we don't do that, which are beyond the scope of this answer and I don't fully understand. But hold on to this thought; it will come up again later.
You can, in principle, make a circuit like this NMOS circuit out of any switching component, or an amplification component (especially if it can be saturated). Over the years, digital logic circuits have been commercially constructed from relays, bipolar junction transistors, and vacuum tubes.
So the final piece of the puzzle is: Why are vacuum tubes useful as switching elements?
This is where we get a little bit into the physics, but it's not difficult to understand the general idea.
In 1853, while trying to understand electric charge, Edmond Becquerel discovered something interesting, which was observed again by Frederick Guthrie in 1873. If you have a hot conductor (like, red hot iron) with a negative charge, it will lose its charge by somehow discharging into the air. However, this won't happen if it has a positive charge.
This is now known as "thermionic emission" or the "Edison effect" (because nothing is ever named after its real discoverer). And we now know that the reason for it is that electrons are negatively charged, so what is happening is that the hot element is emitting electrons.
The reason why we call it the "Edison effect" is that he realised that you could use this to make a circuit element which made current flow in only one direction.

(Image source: Omegatron/Wikipedia.)
In this circuit, the power source at the bottom heats a filament, which also acts as a cathode. If the power source at the right is connected with the positive terminal up, electrons will flow from the hot cathode to the cold anode. If the power source is inverted, no current will flow, because the cold terminal does not emit electrons.
So this is, essentially, a thermionic diode or rectifier, also known as a Fleming valve after John Ambrose Fleming.
Lee de Forest and Robert von Lieben independently worked out that you could also put a control grid between the anode and the cathode. This is essentially a mesh, so that electrons can make it through unless they are attracted to the grid.

This device is known as a triode.
If you don't connect anything to the control grid, this is still essentially a diode. If you connect the control grid to a negative voltage, then the grid repels any electrons emitted from the cathode, and they fly through to the anode. However, if you connect the grid to a positive voltage, the electrons from the cathode land there instead of at the anode, effectively turning the current off.
That is, it is a switching component. And that is how you can make logic elements entirely out of triodes and resistors, much like how you can make logic elements out of N-type MOSFETs and depletion-mode MOSFETs.
Just look at this OR gate circuit from the link you gave:

That's not so hard to understand, when you think about it. It's two transistor-like switching components, and a pull-down resistor to ground. It's not so different from the top half of the CMOS NAND gate, is it?
Of course, this isn't the only possible way to design logic elements from vacuum tubes. In real valve computers, they used tubes with more control grids (e.g. tetrodes and pentodes), and thermionic diodes in a manner similar to diode-transistor logic, and many other techniques besides. This was possible because engineers were very familiar with the properties and characteristics of valves due to them having been used for 40 years in radio applications.
But the basic idea is this: once you have a switching component, you can make a logic element out of it.
